# jQuery autocomplete and jQuery overlays does not work together in the same page

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

my web site uses jquery overlay, and i tried to add jquery autocomplete, but did not work, 
then i re-arranged the script order in the header file as the following:

`<script src="jquery.tools.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`

`<script src="jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`

`<script src="jquery.autocomplete.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`

then autocomplete worked successfully, but the overlays did not work any more.

is there any method to make jquery autocomplete works with jquery overlays at the same page?

Comment: Instead of including jquery.autocomplete include jquery-ui.

Comment: i added the latest version of jquery-ui instead of autocomplete script, but the autocomplete did not work, is there another jquery script file have to load with jquery-ui?